# Struggling to setup SFTP server on mounted HDD (client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset)

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

Attempting to setup an SFTP server on a mounted hard drive, and have followed the instructions from a bunch of tutorials, always get "client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset" on login.

I started by creating a group called sftp, then assigning a user to that group with its home directory in the HDD:

```
sudo useradd -g sftp -d /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME -s /sbin/nologin USERNAME-nas

sudo passwd USERNAME
```

Where USERNAME is my personal username

I then attempted to set ownership of everything above the USERNAME folder to root and the USERNAME folder to the user:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /media

sudo chown -R USERNAME:sftp /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
```

Editted the sshd_config file to contain:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

Match Group sftp
ChrootDirectory /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11 Forwarding no
```

Not forgetting to restart the sshd service

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

As I wanted to access this folder on my linux computer, I set the permissions to 777 for the media folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /media
```

After doing all this, when attempting to login to sftp and entering password I am greeted with:

```
sftp -P PORTNO USERNAME@IP

client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset
Connection closed
```

Is this a permissions issue, or possibly an ownership issue, I don't know. I have spent a long time on this and cannot seem to figure it out, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try running your sftp with `-v` to get verbose debugging.
`sftp -v -P PORTNO USERNAME@IP`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ChrootDirectory /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
[...]
sudo chown -R USERNAME:sftp /media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME
[...]
sudo chmod -R 777 /media
```

The "ChrootDirectory" feature requires that the chroot directory and its parent directories have [certain ownership and permissions](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory):

> **ChrootDirectory**
> Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. At session startup sshd(8) checks that **all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group**. After the chroot, sshd(8) changes the working directory to the user's home directory. Arguments to ChrootDirectory accept the tokens described in the TOKENS section.

There are two issues with the way you set up your chroot directory:

First, `/media`, `/media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME`, and all of the directories in between can't be world- or group-writable. They need to be mode 755 rather than 777.

Second, `/media/linux/MyHDD/NAS/USERNAME` itself has to be owned by root. The directories and files inside it can be owned by the user, but the `USERNAME` directory itself has to be owned by root.

Comment: Thank you! That's it working now. Really appreciate your help!